# How do I initialize variables used for importing libraries in Ride?

Tags: robotframework

I have a custom robot framework library which accepts an argument to initialize it.

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library           NotifyUsers    ${max_messages}
```

This works just fine when executed from the command line using pybot:

```
pybot --variable max_messages:4 my_test
```

However, this variable doesn't exist in Ride when it imports the library at startup.  I've tried defining it in the Arguments field on the Run tab, but that isn't instantiated until you run a test.

If I replace the variable and hard code an integer argument, it works fine in Ride.

Comment: I don't understand _"I've tried defining it in the Arguments field on the Run tab, but that isn't instantiated  until you run a test"_. The variable doesn't need to be defined until you run a test, so what's the problem? is RIDE simply coloring it in a way you don't want?

Comment: Have you considered using a sensible default for max_messages and exposing a keyword in your library to override it? This sounds like a library parameter that is not essential to specify at instantiation and does not need to be a library argument.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ride loads libraries >before< a test is run.  This allows Ride to provide context help, highlighting, etc.  If the library requires a variable, then that variable also needs to exist before run time.  This is the crux of my problem.  When I use a variable as an argument to import the library it doesn't have anything to resolve to and thus the import fails.  When I replace the variable with an integer, it imports just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies to Bryan Oakley!  I somehow managed to delete his answer which pointed me in the right direction.

Adding an entry to the variable table does not resolve this issue, however using a Variable File does!  It appears that Ride will import variable files when it starts up.  Variable Tables contained in a test suite are not resolved until run time.